# Solar System wires seem hot

Tags: temperature

I was checking around the house yesterday for areas that were hot and stumbled across the circuit breaker panel. We have a very large solar array. The picture was taken at peak time of day. I’m a little worried that they undersized the wiring for the system. The breaker was 111 degrees Farenheit and the wiring was over 100 °F. Please look at the pictures. [image]

Comment: So you could boil water on the breaker?

Comment: Flowing electricity has resistance which produces heat.  If not hot enough to burn your skin by touching/holding(not good idea with it on), then it is okay.

Comment: Wires under the bonnet of a car get warmer than that.

Comment: @SolarMike  Maybe if it was reading in Celsius.  Reading is just above luke warm.

Comment: @crip659 I work with 4 temperature systems... But not knowing the one bbeing used is poor - OP that is, not you...

Comment: 111 °F - Not even remarkable. 111 °C there might be something to worry about. 111 °K <brrrrr> 111 ° *Unknown Units* - insufficient information. There does seem to be a box indicating °F on the display, so <yawn>

Comment: What size wire and what's the amperage going through it?  Neither of those temps are "hot" so to speak.  Picture shows deg F  so that's what I'm assuming..

Comment: Automotive wiring under the bonnet area dependent are required to properly function at 150C to 175 C ambient depending on OEM. House wiring is not designed to operate anywhere near that. 111.5  - 69.5 = equal a 42F temperature rise, still in the rating of the wire assuming 60C rating so no worry.

Comment: @SolarMike At 111 degrees you'd be lucky to boil *nitrogen*. That's frickin' cold.

Answer (score 3):

111 °F or 43.89 °C is an utterly unremarkable temperature for wires or breakers. Warm, at most, not "hot."

60°C (140 °F) is the lowest wire/cable rating, most breakers and some cables/wires are rated for 75 °C (167°F), and many wires are rated for 90 °C (194°F)

Nothing to be concerned about from these measurements, particularly at "peak solar array output."

Comment: If, instead, you wanted to ask the (different, new, question) "Are my solar array wires big enough?" you should ask that question, and provide plenty of gory details about the array, inverters, wire sizes, breaker sizes, etc. That *appears to be* what the (current) other answers here are trying to answer, rather than this question. The temperatures from this question do not suggest that there's any particular concern, and presumably your array installation was inspected and passed inspection, and undersized wiring would not pass inspection.

Answer (score 1):

While 111 °F is well within the limits of US standard wiring practices, that does not mean it is "normal". It might be, it might not. There are basically three likely possibilities:

- Everything is OK

That means wire sized correctly for the peak load (or in this case, peak generation capacity), breakers sized correctly to protect the wire and the rest of the panel sized appropriately. The rest of the panel comes into play because the size of the utility service, size of the generation capacity, capacity of the breaker panel bus, and maybe some other things I haven't thought of, all factor into appropriate solar hookups.

- Wires are too small

If the wires are appropriate for 50A and you add more panels and now have 75A (making up numbers at random), you probably need to upgrade the wires. Or wires may have never been sized appropriately in the first place.

- Something wasn't installed correctly

Anyone's guess, but there are a lot of things that can be done wrong yet seem to work just fine most of the time. There are a *lot* of details that go into a proper solar installation.

Impossible to say without more details. Pictures of the actual panel, showing all the breakers with the solar connection identified and also showing the wiring diagram (typically on the inside of the panel door) would help, along with any details about the solar panels, inverter, etc.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain what I did wrong?

Comment: You trying to unmask the DVer???  Good luck... I hate those guys.. :-)

Comment: @JACK I don't get a *lot* of downvotes, so I don't think it is personal. Which leaves open the question of what part (or style or whatever) of my answer is "bad".

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing there, is not how we do this thing.

### Compare the nameplate ampacity to the wire rating.

You start with you solar panels and their array pattern. You typically have a series string or a series-parallel array (say 10 in series x 3 in parallel).  Each of your matched panels has a number of ratings.   We're concerned with 2 numbers here.

For "microinverter" panels, all microinverters are in parallel (so 1 series x *n* parallels) and you will need to look at their specs and the spec of the panel feeding them to figure out ampacity.  The microinverters run at normal AC mains frequency (240V North America or 230V Europe).

Voltage.  Find the "open circuit voltage", say it is 38 volts.  Multiply this by the number of series (say 10 in series).   Multiply "open circuit voltage" x number in series.  That will give system open-circuit volts.   (e.g. 38 x 10 = 380 volts).  **The wire must have a voltage rating >= that**.

Current.  (what you're concerned with today). Find "short circuit current", or the current that would flow if you shorted its leads together* in ideal conditions.  That is the worst case current.   Multiply this current by the number in parallel. Say your array is 10x3 (3 paralleled) and your short circuit current is 10 amps, your answer is 30 amps.  **The wire must be of a size sufficient for these amps**.

As long as it is rated for the amps, you are all set. The wire is thermally rated for that ampacity.

### What about heat losses? Aren't we throwing money away?

Maybe.  Since you only get the nameplate amps during shorting conditions, you need to measure the real-world amps.  If it is DC you will need a DC rated ammeter; a common clamp AC meter won't do much.   Likewise you need real-world volts, since open-circuit voltage is a fantasy number.

Once you have amps, volts, wire length and wire size (typically in AWG or mm<sup>2</sup>), you can go to a "voltage drop calculator" and it will tell you the percentage of energy loss.

You can then try it with different wire sizes to see how a larger wire size will result in less energy loss. From there you can figure out the economics of changing out the wire.

Pay careful mind to the [wire type](https://www.ecmweb.com/national-electrical-code/article/20897202/wiring-methods-for-pv-systems-and-the-nec).  Aluminum wire can be helpful for providing ridiculous ampacity at low cost, but that only works if the wire is rated for solar power.  Remember a solar system is usually high voltage DC - not to be trifled with.

Given copper prices *right now*, you may find enlarging the wire would be a net lose.  Check again when everything has returned to normal.

---

---

* A solar panel is a current-limited source; shorting it does not harm.  It gets warm from the high current flow, but this flow comes from solar energy it is converting to electricity... which would otherwise turn to heat!  So it simply gets the normal heat it would have if it was turned off.

Comment: This explanation sounds like it is describing (in one variant) DC current. But the big wires (the ones in the heat picture) going from the solar "system" to the breaker panel would be AC.

Comment: @manassehkatz only the wires from the inverter to the breaker panel.  From panel to inverter you're DC.  Of course inverters can be in different places and OP has been unclear on this point.